# Snowflake Dynamic SQL to select subset of columns in one table from undetermined number of values in another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-sql

I need to create a SQL script that will run daily and select a subset of columns from table A.
The subset of columns is defined in table B - it will be periodically edited by marketing team and can have any subset of the columns in table A

example:

```
Table_A has 100 columns: [Column1], [Column2], ..., [Column100]

Table_B has 1 column: [ColumnNames] with the values 'Column1', 'Column3', 'Column8'
```

How do I write a dynamic query

```
SELECT **Column1, Column3, Column8**
FROM Table_A
```

where the list of columns (in bold) comes from the query

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT ColumnNames, ', ')
FROM Table_B
```

I tried the following:

```
SET ColumnList = (SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT ColumnNames, ', ') FROM Table_B );
SET SQLScript = (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', $ColumnList, ' FROM Table_A'));
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $SQLScript;
```

This works well as long as the character size of the variable SQLScript does not exceed 256, but I cannot count on that being true since marketing may select to include many ColumnNames in Table_B

Comment: Use this style : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the style as suggested by @Mat on their comment, with 500 columns:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
    BEGIN   
        let concat_cols string := (
            select listagg(x, ', ') 
            from (select a.$1 x from values('a'),('b'),('c') a 
            join (select 1 from TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 500))))
            );
        let long_select string := 'select ' || concat_cols || ' from (select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c)';
        let res resultset := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE long_select);
        return table(res);
    END;
$$
;
```

These variables don't have the 256 character limit.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Felipe! This got me 99% of the way. My last hurdle is how within the block to insert the resultset into a temp table (apologies if basic, I'm a newbie)

Comment: I tried to create the temp table before the block and then in the block (after let res resultset) added INSERT INTO <temp_table> SELECT * FROM res;     I get an error:   SQL Error [2003] [42S02]: Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 11 at position 6 : SQL compilation error:
Object 'RES' does not exist or not authorized.

Comment: You can't `select from resultset` (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets#limitations-of-the-resultset-data-type), but what instead of running `select ....` you ran `create table xx as select ...`? (Please accept and upvote this answer if it answered your original question)

Comment: This completely solved my problem - thank you very much for your time. I accepted the answer (cannot yet upvote since I am new and have not yet achieved the reputation score required).